# Check if is admin on login, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have 3 tables:

- users (store all users)
- roles (store all roles)
- role_users (relationship between) ->(id, role_id, user_id)

I want to restrict some routes if user in not admin, but I am not sure how.

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::before(function ($user, $role) {
        // 
    });
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::middleware(['can:admin'])->group(function () {
  //
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using it now in the middleware, I think you simply have to define the `admin` gate.

In your `AuthServiceProvider`, try something like this:

```
Gate::define('admin', function ($user) {
    return $user->isAdmin();
});
```

where `$user->isAdmin()` should be replaced with the code that determines whether the user is an admin.
So, assuming you have a role called  `admin`, you could do:

```
Gate::define('admin', function ($user) {
    return !empty($user->roles()->where('name', 'admin')->first());
});
```

On a little side-note. According to Laravel conventions, your many-to-many table should have singular naming. So instead of naming the table  `role_users` you should name it `role_user`. Otherwise you would have to specify the name in each of the model relations.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)  package for the role based authorization and permissions. It is an awesome package. This package is well documented and easy to use.

Comment: I already created my structure, but good to know for future references.